# Is it possible to set dynamic marq text and logo into a video stream recording using libvlcsharp?

Tags: libvlcsharp

Good day to you all,
I have a problem, maybe someone can provide some helpful ideas on how to implement or if it's even possible:
I want to record RTSP stream from an IP-cam and I would like to add some text information and logo into the recording so it might be viewed when played back.
To do so I have first created one MediaPlayer element to connect to the IP-cam, duplicate onto the display, and recast via UDP.

```
using (var stream01_view = new Media(libVLC, "rtsp://192.168.10.214:5554",FromType.FromLocation))
{
    stream01_view.AddOption(
            ":sout=#duplicate{" +
            "dst=display{noaudio}," +
            "dst=std{access=udp,mux=ts,dst=:1234}");
    stream01_view.AddOption(":sout-keep");
    player.Play(stream01_view);
}
```

The second stream connects to the local UDP cast and outputs to file

```
using (var stream01_record = new Media(libVLC, "udp://@:1234", FromType.FromLocation))
{
    stream01_record.AddOption(":sout=#transcode{sfilter=marq}:file{mux=ts,dst=VideoMarqLogo.mp4}");
    stream01_record.AddOption(":sout-keep");
    recorder.Play(stream01_record); 
}
```

Calling class `MediaPlayer` methods `SetMarqueeInt` and `SetMarqueeString` don't give the expected result.

Comment: Share full verbose logs

Comment: use sfilter=logo https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=144084

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [mfkl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4064749/mfkl) for pointing to the right direction.
So the thing that does the trick is:

```
stream01_record.AddOption(":sout=#transcode{ vcodec=h264, scale=0.75, " +
                    "sfilter=marq{file='marq.txt',position=9}," +
                    "vfilter=logo{file='logo.png',position=6}}" +
                   ":file{mux=ts,dst=VideoMarqLogo.mp4}");
```

A bit of a warning though, this piece of code is CPU intensive. 
I'm left wondering if there could be a way to do this using GPU encoding.

Comment: Yes, using libvlc 4, it is possible to do custom rendering like this using only the GPU for best performance